# Desktop or Taskbar shortcut of shellscript - easiest way with 18.04 LTS?

Tags: scripts, shortcut-keys, launcher

I'm new to ubuntu and Linux and just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I know there are tons of tutorials out there how someone could create a shortcut. Unfortunately none of them really worked for me.

I have a `~/shellscript.sh` which I'd need to call periodically.

How can I create a shellscript launcher as simply as

e.g. `ln -s ~/shellscript.sh ~/Desktop/run-shellscript`

where I simply can click on it to run it? (Remark: `ln` command above doesn't work)

Thanks for your contributions!

Comment: Found this and tried this before without success.

I tried the following:

start-xmr-stak.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Test
Comment=Test
Exec=~/Desktop/xmr-stak-bin/xmr-stak
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=false
GenericName=Test


note: shortcut and script are executable


Dialogue appears: "There was an error launching the application" - OK button

Comment: @ssssstut you need to use full path, the `~` in  `Exec=~/Desktop...` won't be interpreted as user's home, because that's a feature of a shell. `.desktop` files do not run in shell.  So use  `Exec=/home/your_username/Desktop/`, full path

Comment: when I use Exec=/home/user/xmr-stak/build/bin/xmr-stak the program gets called however the configs in the direcory are not found. When I modify the .desktop accordingly it doesn't work:          path=/home/user/xmr-stak/build/bin/
                 Exec=xmr-stak

Comment: solved. used this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arronax
nautilus -q

[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Name=XMR-STAK

Comment=run xmr stak

Exec=/home/user/xmr-stak/build/bin/xmr-stak
Terminal=true
Hidden=false

Name=xmr-stak

Path=/home/user/xmr-stak/build/bin/

Icon=utilities-terminal